# how can i use cout<<"hello world"; without using ; at the end of the line

Tags: c++, cout

I want to display hello world message in c++ without using semicolon. how can I do that? Is it possible?
I have tried it inside if else block like

```
if(true) {
cout<<"hello world"

}
```

but it does not work like that.

Comment: why? you can put the `;` on the next line if that helps

Comment: that begs the question why you want to do that. The ';' is used in C++ to declare statements. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements

Comment: You do know that the semicolon is C++ syntax for ending a statement and that it won't be part of the printed string - right?

Answer (score 6):

```
if (cout << "hello world") {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it as the condition:

```
if (std::cout << "hello world") {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if`, `for` or `while`, maybe more.

```
if(std::cout << "Hello World") { }

while(std::cout << "Hello World" && false) { } // && false to loop only once

for(std::cout << "Hello World"; false;) { } // has semicolons, but not at the end of line ;)
```

Or put it on the next line:

```
std::cout << "Hello World 4"\
;
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the the new-line in your last example.  Simply put the `;` on the next line without any `\ ` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to write Hello world message without using semi-colon like If condition as,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    if(cout<<"Hello World")
    return 0;
}
```